# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: api, .net-core

I have deployed a .NET Core API on Nginx server on Linux. My API internally calls third party API using HTTPClient.PostAsJsonAsync method.

System is working fine in normal load, but in case of heavy load i am getting below error.

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Cannot assign requested address\n   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host,
> Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   --- End of inner
> exception stack trace ---\n   at
> System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at
> System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()\n   at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()\n
> at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask,
> HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean
> disposeCts)\n   at
> MyCard.Middleware.Controllers.DefaultController.CallAndGetESBResponse(Object
> requestModel, API apiInfo)

Can any one help me to solve this?

Comment: Looks like youre either giving it bad credentials or there is already a service bound to that address